# Robot Middleware (OpenRTM, OROCOS, RSCA, ASEBA etc.) support port to an RTOS(Micrium, QNX, Keil, FreeRTOS?

Tags: middleware, robotics, rtos, qnx, micrium

I have question to ask you.

There are some open source robotic middleware out there that contains some libraries for robotic developers to do I/O works. They are really powerfull tools that save a lot of time.
They are such as **OpenRTM**, **OROCOS**, **RSCA** etc...

In a project, we will developing a robotic wheelchair that do some autonomous behaviors such as obstacle avoidance, move2goal, follow coridor etc. We'll use an RTOS to organize I/O stuff and selection operations for the behaviors.

What I'm wondering is if any of the RTOS(**mcOS-II, QNX, Keil** etc.) has port to these middlewares? Can I install them on to these RTOSes?

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you got what I mean.

My best regards..

Comment: It's ROS everywhere now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am OpenRTM-aist user.

OpenRTM-aist have QNX implementation.

http://www.openrtm.org/openrtm/ja/node/5056

Sorry, there is no english documentation for OpenRTM for QNX, please use google translate button on the site.

OpenRTM-aist is also available for Real-Time Linux (ART-Linux, real-time preemption kernel), T-Kernel (uITRON), VxWorks (developed by SEC CO. LTD.).

Sorry, they do not have english pages, but developers are of course available for english communication. Ask them in the mailiing list: I also recommend you to use openrtm-user mailing list. We had a similar question a couple days ago. You must be able to get some useful information on it.

You can find link on the official OpenRTM-aist website, described above.

Of course, english is welcome!

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to be helpful, but please don't deliberately circumvent new user restrictions in the future. Your recommendation is OK, but there must be a _single_ link you can use, while adding more context? If you'd like to edit this, flag it once done and we'll have a look.